# Why SecurityHub does not show my Config finding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-hub

So I have enabled Control Tower on my organization. I deployed one ConfigRule through Control tower (rds encrypted). I deployed my Security Hub.

When I look on Control Tower I see the my bad RDS for my account. But if I look on Security Hub, even if my account is detected, it does not find the defective RDS.

Am I missing something ?